# Basic drop-down menu (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, drop-down-menu

I'm using this currently:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul#nav > li').hover(function () {
        $('ul:first', this).show();
    },
    function () {
        $('ul:first', this).hide();
    });
    $('ul#nav li li').hover(function () {
        $('ul:first', this).each(function () {
            $(this).css('top', $(this).parent().position().top);
            $(this).css('left', $(this).parent().position().left + $(this).parent().width());
            $(this).show();
        });
    },
    function () {
        $('ul:first', this).hide();
    });
});
```

..can it be improved/compacted further?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store `$(this).parent` in variable and chain functions, other than that it looks pretty straightforward (and i write anonym single line functions on one line)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul#nav > li').hover(function () { $('ul:first', this).show(); },
                           function () { $('ul:first', this).hide(); }
    );
    $('ul#nav li li').hover(function () {
        $('ul:first', this).each(function () {
            var p = $(this).parent();
            $(this).css('top', p.position().top)
                   .css('left', p.position().left + p.width())
                   .show();
        });},
        function () { $('ul:first', this).hide(); }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely replace:

```
$(this).css('top', $(this).parent().position().top);
$(this).css('left', $(this).parent().position().left + $(this).parent().width());
$(this).show();
```

with:

```
var element = $(this);
var parent = element.parent();
var position = parent.position();
element.css('top', position.top);
element.css('left', position.left + parent.width());
element.show();
```